# Get Woocommerce to automatically assigns product categories using keyword in product title

Tags: php, arrays, object, woocommerce, strpos

Firstly let me make it clear I have very little to no coding experience whatsoever, so here goes.

I am trying to create a custom PHP code for Woocommerce, the aim is to automatically assign products to product categories by matching a set keyword string that would be found in product titles. I would like this to execute either when importing, updating, changing, or saving a product.

I have found other methods of achieving this however I have not found a way to simply add object_terms.
Here is the code I have created from other codes I already have for other purposes, I have tried to edit the code to meet my requirement. Here is what I have compiled so far.

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_product_quick_edit_save', 'get_cat_from_title',150,1 );
    // On admin single product creation/update
    add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'get_cat_from_title',100,1);
    // On admin single product variation creation/update
    add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'get_cat_from_title' ,100,1);
    add_action( 'save_post_product', 'get_cat_from_title' ,100,1);
    add_action( 'save_product_category', 'get_cat_from_title' ,100,1);
  // Update below //  function get_cat_from_title($title,$defaultcat) {
  // function get_cat_from_title($title) {
    function get_cat_from_title( $product_id) { 
        
    // get an instance of the WC_Product Object
        if (is_object($product_id)){
            $product  = $product_id;
            $product_id=$product->get_id();
        }else{
            $product  = wc_get_product( $product_id );
        }
                    
    // keyword in title - 'test1'
                if (strpos($title,'test1') !== false){
                    // category for found keyword 'test1'
                    $cat = "test1";
                    // category for found keyword 'test2'
    } elseif(strpos($title,"test2") !== false);{      
                $cat = "test2";
    
            switch ($cat) {
            // assign category test1
            case 'test1':
                    wp_add_object_terms ( $product_id,'test1', 'product_cat' );
                    break;  
            // assign category test2
            case 'test2':
                    wp_add_object_terms ( $product_id,'test2', 'product_cat' );
                break;
            default:
                # code...
                break;
            }
                }
    }
```

Unfortunately, the code is not working for me and throws the following errors inside my debug.log.

```
[27-Jan-2021 12:25:51 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'data' of non-object in /home/pub/domain.com/wp-content/plugins/bdthemes-element-pack/base/element-pack-base.php on line 471
[27-Jan-2021 12:25:54 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'data' of non-object in /home/pub/domain.com/wp-content/plugins/bdthemes-element-pack/base/element-pack-base.php on line 471
[27-Jan-2021 12:26:09 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'data' of non-object in /home/pub/domain.com/wp-content/plugins/bdthemes-element-pack/base/element-pack-base.php on line 471
[27-Jan-2021 12:26:10 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'data' of non-object in /home/pub/domain.com/wp-content/plugins/bdthemes-element-pack/base/element-pack-base.php on line 471
[27-Jan-2021 12:26:11 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function get_cat_from_title(), 1 passed in /home/pub/domain.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 289 and exactly 2 expected in /home/pub/domain.com/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/snippet-ops.php(446) : eval()'d code:8
Stack trace:
#0 /home/pub/domain.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(289): get_cat_from_title(443439)
#1 /home/pub/domain.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#2 /home/pub/domain.com/wp-includes/plugin.php(484): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#3 /home/pub/domain.com/wp-includes/post.php(4298): do_action('save_post_produ...', 443439, Object(WP_Post), true)
#4 /home/pub/domain.com/wp-includes/post.php(4411): wp_insert_post(Array, false, true)
#5 /home/pub/domain.com/wp-a in /home/pub/domain.com/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/snippet-ops.php(446) : eval()'d code on line 8
[27-Jan-2021 12:26:24 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'data' of non-object in /home/pub/domain.com/wp-content/plugins/bdthemes-element-pack/base/element-pack-base.php on line 471
[27-Jan-2021 12:26:25 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'data' of non-object in /home/pub/domain.com/wp-content/plugins/bdthemes-element-pack/base/element-pack-base.php on line 471
```

Admin usually tells me off for not writing my questions clearly or correctly, I am not a developer I do not understand all of the jargon however I really do hope that I have posted this correctly and explained my goal clearly enough! Maybe someone can tell me where I am going wrong and how to make this code work with some edits. I am open to comments and always willing to learn. Thank you :)

Comment: Just remove unused `, $defaultcat` from your function argument, it should solve the fatal error.

Comment: Thank you, yes that seemed to resolve the fatal error. :) Debug log now says that my only errors are on lines 12 + 16 + 33 due to an Undefined variable: product_id in my code. The code I am using is a modified auto in stock tag and category assigner. I will do some more testing. Thank you again :)

Comment: replacing function with; function get_cat_from_title( $product_id) { seems to get category test2 assigned to product titled test2, just not assigning test1. I am really enjoying this, so satisfying to make progress. :D

Comment: Your code can't work as all used hooks doesn't have any title as main function argument… The main argument is the WC_Product object for some of them and the product_id for some others… So there is no keywords to find. From the `WC_Product` object you can get the title using `get_name()` method

Comment: You are correct, although the code appeared to work in some way it actually broke all products and their assigned categories, luckily I had a backup to restore from. Think it's best to get a developer to create this as it's quite dangerous if done incorrectly.